# Получить Count() в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Такой запрос вернул мне все, что нужно

```
var galleries = db.Query(@"SELECT Galleries.Id, Galleries.Name, COUNT(Photos.Id) AS PhotoCount FROM Galleries LEFT OUTER JOIN Photos ON Galleries.Id = Photos.GalleryId GROUP BY Galleries.Id, Galleries.Name").ToList();
// а этот не хочет
var CountPhotos = db.Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Photos").ToList();
```

Первый работает, второй - не так, как нужно. Второй вернул `1`, а должен был `9`. Пути проверил все верно.

```
 <p>Существует альбомов: @galleries.Count Всего фотографий: @CountPhotos.Count</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT всегда возвращает таблицу. Второй запрос возвращает таблицу с одной колонкой (COUNT(id)) и одной (!) строкой:

COUNT(id)
100500

А когда вы пишете `db.Query(...).ToList().Count`, то вам возвращается количество записей в этой самой таблице, т.е. 1.

Вам нужно просто вытащить значение счетчика, что-то типа:

```
var CountPhotos = db.Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Photos").ToList()[0][0];
```

А потом:

```
 <p>Существует альбомов: @galleries.Count Всего фотографий: @CountPhotos</p>
```